# Programmatically adding an endpoint

Tags: wcf, wcf-endpoint

I have a WCF service that I am connecting in client application. I am using following in configuration file.

```
<system.serviceModel>  
    <bindings>  
      <basicHttpBinding>  
        <binding name="MyNameSpace.TestService" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"  
            receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"  
            bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"  
            maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"  
            messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"  
            useDefaultWebProxy="true">  
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="16384"  
              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />  
          <security mode="None">  
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"  
                realm="" />  
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />  
          </security>  
        </binding>  
      </basicHttpBinding>  
    </bindings>  
    <client>  
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:9100/TestService" binding="basicHttpBinding"  
          bindingConfiguration="MyNameSpace.TestService" contract="TestService.IService" name="MyNameSpace.TestService" />  
    </client>  
</system.serviceModel>
```

In the code, I am calling API on this service as follows,

```
TestServiceClient client = new TestServiceClient()
client.BlahBlah()
```

Now I want to defined endpoint porgramatically. How can that be done? I commented out  section from config file as I was thinking I will have to put some code on TestServiceClient instance to add endpoint dynamically but then it throws following exception at the point where TestServiceClient is instantiated.

> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract
>   'TestService.IService' in the ServiceModel client configuration
>   section. This might be because no configuration file was found for
>   your application, or because no endpoint element matching this
>   contract could be found in the client element.

How can I accomplish this? Also any point on code examples for adding endpoint programmatically will be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To create endpoints and bindings programmatically, you could do this on the service:

```
ServiceHost _host = new ServiceHost(typeof(TestService), null);

var _basicHttpBinding = new System.ServiceModel.basicHttpBinding();
            //Modify your bindings settings if you wish, for example timeout values
            _basicHttpBinding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(4, 0, 0);
            _basicHttpBinding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(4, 0, 0);
            _host.AddServiceEndpoint(_basicHttpBinding, "http://192.168.1.51/TestService.svc");
            _host.Open();
```

You could also define multiple endpoints in your service config, and choose which one to connect to dynamically at run time.

On the client program you would then do this:

```
basicHttpBinding _binding = new basicHttpBinding();
EndpointAddress _endpoint = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("http://192.168.1.51/TestService.svc"));

TestServiceClient _client = new TestServiceClient(_binding, _endpoint);
_client.BlahBlah();
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you just use:

```
TestServiceClient client = new TestServiceClient();
client.Endpoint.Address = new EndPointAddress("http://someurl");
client.BlahBlah();
```

Note that your binding configuration will no longer apply, as you're not using that endpoint configuration in your configuration file.  You'll have to override that, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
TestServiceClient client = new TestServiceClient("MyNameSpace.TestService")
client.BlahBlah()
```

if not recheck namespace in file TestService is correct?